High values in elevation from GEDI and NaN values in the rh metrics
I'm working with GEDI data to model AGB and distinguish between different forest compositions (such as dense agroforestry systems and native forests). I downloaded the data from Earth Data using a smaller AOI and obtained data from L1B, L2A, and L2B levels.
The area of interest is flat, and the elevation varies between 0 and 937 meters. However, when I plot the waveform from this specific area, it returns values around 4225 meters. Additionally, when I try to apply the rh metrics, the values are NaN.
I used the rGEDI package as follow :
library(rGEDI)
library(BiocManager)

# Definir o diretório contendo os arquivos .h5
outdir <- "C:/DOUTORADO_ECOLOGIA/rGEDI"

# Reading GEDI data
gedilevel1b <- readLevel1B("C:/DOUTORADO_ECOLOGIA/rGEDI/GEDI01_B_002-20240929_175348/GEDI01_B_2019310231930_O05109_01_T04587_02_005_01_V002.h5")
gedilevel2a <- readLevel2A("C:/DOUTORADO_ECOLOGIA/rGEDI/GEDI02_A_002-20240929_190258/GEDI02_A_2019158114458_O02743_01_T03164_02_003_01_V002.h5")
gedilevel2b <- readLevel2B("C:/DOUTORADO_ECOLOGIA/rGEDI/GEDI02_B_002-20240929_175637/GEDI02_B_2019310231930_O05109_01_T04587_02_003_01_V002.h5")

level1bGeo <- getLevel1BGeo(level1b=gedilevel1b, select=c("elevation_bin0"))
head(level1bGeo)

# Extracting GEDI full-waveform for a given shot number 
wf <- getLevel1BWF(gedilevel1b, shot_number="51090000100000002")

par(mfrow = c(1,2), mar=c(4,4,1,1), cex.axis = 1.5)

plot(wf, relative=FALSE, polygon=TRUE, type="l", lwd=2, col="forestgreen",
     xlab="Waveform Amplitude", ylab="Elevation (m)")
grid()
plot(wf, relative=TRUE, polygon=FALSE, type="l", lwd=2, col="forestgreen",
     xlab="Waveform Amplitude (%)", ylab="Elevation (m)")
grid()

# Reading GEDI data
level1b <- readLevel1B("C:/DOUTORADO_ECOLOGIA/rGEDI/GEDI01_B_002-20240929_175348/GEDI01_B_2019310231930_O05109_01_T04587_02_005_01_V002.h5")
level2a <- readLevel2A("C:/DOUTORADO_ECOLOGIA/rGEDI/GEDI02_A_002-20240929_190258/GEDI02_A_2019158114458_O02743_01_T03164_02_003_01_V002.h5")
level2b <- readLevel2B("C:/DOUTORADO_ECOLOGIA/rGEDI/GEDI02_B_002-20240929_175637/GEDI02_B_2019310231930_O05109_01_T04587_02_003_01_V002.h5")

level2AM <- getLevel2AM(gedilevel2a)
head(level2AM[,c("beam","shot_number","elev_highestreturn","elev_lowestmode","rh100")])

shot_number = "51090000100000002"

png("fig8.png", width = 8, height = 6, units = 'in', res = 300)
plotWFMetrics(gedilevel1b, gedilevel2a, shot_number, rh=c(25, 50, 75, 90))
dev.off()


GEDI data can sometimes show unexpected elevation values in areas where you would expect lower values.
One main factor influencing this is could be terrain (e.g., slope). Additionally, the time of day can impact data quality, as changes in atmospheric conditions or sun angle can affect lidar returns.
For NaN values, the first thing to check is the quality flag associated with each shot. GEDI provides a quality flag that indicates the reliability of the data. A flag of 1 signifies that the shot meets certain conditions, such as sufficient energy and sensitivity.
I'd first try filtering by this flag and seeing how many NaN values remain.
